# How to do URL rewriting in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, url-rewriting

In Classic ASP I want to convert links into user friendly urs.For example
http://www.sportsmanager.us/links/AboutUs.asp?Org=504&Link=7514 
should convert to 
http://www.sportsmanager.us/links/demo/AboutUs
Please let me know is it possible in classic asp.We have window server 2003 standard edition and IIS6.0.

Thanks, Ravi

Answer (score 1):

Try http://iirf.codeplex.com/ (free) or http://www.isapirewrite.com (free to try)

Comment: ISAPI_Rewrite is a great tool. v2 is free if you don't mind single config for entire server, v3 is (mostly) compatible with Apache .haccess rules so is easier to get into.  Either option are pretty cheap to buy.